# Birthday problem for increasing population size

Tags: probability, probability-theory

My intuition tells me that if I sample $K$ samples, with replacement, from a population of size $N$, the probability of getting unique $K$ samples should be increasing as $N$ increases.

I wrote a simple simulation in python. Population size $N$ (x-axis) ranges from $365$ to $1000$.

[image: Probability of duplicate samples in an increasing population]

To my surprise, the probability seems to be steadily decreasing. Any hints as to whats going on here?

Comment: You say the x axis ranges from 365 to 1000 but the graph says 0 to 12. What does your graph actually represent?

Comment: I think your question assumes we know all the details of your simulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your intuition should be correct. I'm not horrible at Python, can you tell me what you put it for your simulation?

If I've understood you correctly, you're looking at a formula like: $(1)(\frac{N-1}{N})(\frac{N-2}{N})...(\frac{N-K}{N})$, which clearly would increase the bigger the population.

Uhm, did you accidentally calculate the probability of not getting unique samples?
If not, then I believe it's a mistake in your Python.

Comment: Just found the bug. I was looping to $K-1$ in the numerator in stead of $K$. Thanks